# Direct current from curl in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

From differential form of the Ampère-Maxwell equation,
$$\nabla\times{\bf H} = {\bf J} + \frac{\partial\bf D}{\partial t}$$
a curl in magnetic field $\bf H$ is established by a current density $\bf J$ and a time-varying displacement current $\bf D$.

It doesn't seem like the opposite should be true, that a magnetic field with non-zero curl at some point creates a current density or time-varying displacement current. If an infinitely-long wire was placed parallel to the x-axis in a field described by ${\bf H} = y\hat{k}$ would this result in some direct current in the wire? What am I failing to consider?

Comment: It's the other way round. You need a current $I({\bf x})\propto (1,0,0)$ to *create* a field such as ${\bf B}= (0,0,y)$.

Comment: @mikestone What if the field was set up by some other source, would the wire have a current? I understand that current density creates a circulating magnetic field, but does the same hold true in reverse?

Comment: What current distribution would you use to set up the field ${\bf B}({\bf x})=(0,0,y)$?

Comment: @mikestone Not the same field, but would another parallel wire in the vicinity carrying some current not establish curl? Or is the point you're making that the case where non-zero curl outside of the source not possible?

Comment: You have it correctly!  non-zero curl outside the source is not possible.

Comment: @mikestone Would you mind putting this as an answer? This is what I needed to know. Although I might need some help understanding why it is always zero outside the source.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic fields are produced by moving electric charges and the intrinsic magnetic moments of elementary particles associated with a fundamental quantum property, their spin. You need current density or moving charges to produce a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Ampère-Maxwell equation establishes a relation between three fundamental fields in electrodynamics: ${\bf J}$, ${\bf H}$, and ${\bf D}$. The way such a relation can be interpreted depends on the details of the physical situation.

If the current ${\bf J}$ is an externally controlled physical quantity, it may be considered as a source in the full set of Maxwell equations. However, although common in many applications,  this is a simplification of a more general situation where ${\bf J}$, or part of it, may depend on the fields. In this case, a self-consistent solution of the full set of Maxwell equations and the constitutive relation ${\bf J}={\bf J}({\bf E},{\bf B})$ is required. In such situations, it isn't very meaningful either to consider ${\bf J}$ as *the source* of the fields or to look at the curl of ${\bf H}$ as the origin of the current.

Comment: In the hypothetical situation where $\nabla \times {\bf H}$ is externally controlled, would this produce $\bf J$ or $\bf D$, or is it still not meaningful to consider? I'm under the impression that such a case is not physically realizable.

Comment: @FelixWong from the formal point of view, if curl of H is given then one gets the rhs of the corresponding Maxwell equation. However, from the practical point of view, I would have a hard time finding an experimental way to obtain it. In every case, I would hesitate to say that one side of the equation produces the other side. The meaningful concept is what is really controlled and fixed in an experiment.